# Animation isn't working because the picbox doesn't reset and the task doesn't sleep

Tags: c#, animation, bitmap

I have this code right here:
EDIT: Source Code:

```
        private void btnAnimate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap[] circle = new Bitmap[300];
            for (int i = 0; i < circle.Length; i++)
            {
                circle[i] = new Bitmap(260, 266);
            }
            double r = 25; // radius
            double rr = Math.Pow(r, 2); // r^2

            int h = 25; 
            // x value of centre of circle is represented with h and y value is represented with k
            for (int k = 25; k <= 100; k += 25) // y value of center moves down 1 pixel every iteration
            {
                
                for (int x = -h; x <= h + r; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = -k; y <= k + r; y++)
                    {
                        if (Math.Abs(Math.Pow(x - h, 2) + Math.Pow(y - k, 2)) <= rr)
                        // if: |(x-h)^2 + (y - h)^2| <= r^2, then draw the pixel
                        {
                           
                            circle[k - 25].SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int l = 25; l <= 100; l+= 25)
            {
                picBox.Image = circle[l - 25];
                btnAnimate.Text = "circle" + (l/25);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
```

(it use to be k++ but I made it k+= 25 so it would make it easier to trouble shoot, it will only draw 4 circles instead of the original 75.)

and I want it to draw a circle on a picture box (I've tested it and it can do that), but afterwards I want it to sleep for a while, then clear the picture box, draw a new circle only 1 pixel below it and repeat until the circle hits the ground. The problem with this is that the program is sleeping but it isn't showing the action done in between sleeps. i.e it says to show circle 1 then sleep until it reaches circle 4, but it will not show circles 1 through 3 though it will sleep, it will just show the final circle. It's not even just the pic box

you can see that I wrote

```
                btnAnimate.Text = "circle" + (l/25);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

I want it to change the button text to 1, 2, 3, and 4 to count each iteration but it doesn't do that either. it will just show 4 at the end.

What do you think the problem is?

Solution:

```
            

            double r = 25; // radius
            double rr = Math.Pow(r, 2); // r^2

            int h = 25; 
            // x value of centre of circle is represented with h and y value is represented with k
            for (int k = 25; k <= 100; k += 25) // y value of center moves down 1 pixel every iteration
            {
                Bitmap circle = new Bitmap(260, 266);
                for (int x = -h; x <= h + r; x++)
                {
                    for (int y = -k; y <= k + r; y++)
                    {
                        if (Math.Abs(Math.Pow(x - h, 2) + Math.Pow(y - k, 2)) <= rr)
                        // if: |(x-h)^2 + (y - h)^2| <= r^2, then draw the pixel
                        {
                           
                            circle.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Red);
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
                picBox.Image = circle;
                picBox.Update();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
```

Comment: I fixed the not resetting problem. I realized it was because I wasn't resetting the bitmap object. So I just created a 300 bitmap array and each iteration it creates a new a bitmap. Now the only problem is the threading.sleep. In between each sleep, it fails to show the image. It will wait 100 milliseconds, not show the image, then go on until it reaches the final image. What's up with that?

Comment: There are a lot of UI environments in .NET. Which one do you use? Please use tags to indicate such things. And do not post source code as a screenshot. Include it in the post as text; otherwise, you just make it difficult for others to test your code and to help you.

Comment: You should either be using a Timer, or switch to the Async/Await model.

Comment: You can't use `Thread.Sleep` to make something on the UI animate, since the thread you're putting to sleep is the UI update thread, meaning nothing will refresh while it's asleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems:

1. You are not clearing the `Bitmap circle` drawn circle on each iteration, so you are building upon the previous drawn circle, so it looks like a falling circle with trails.  You can fix this by defining your `Bitmap circle` inside of the first for loop, instead of outside.
2. It is failing to show the new image inbetween Thread sleeps because you are not telling the control to refresh itself visually.  Do this by calling `picBox.Update()` or `picBox.Refresh()` after you set `picBox.Image = circle`.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks  a lot! I realized the first problem but your solution is much more efficient than creating 300 bitmab objects lol. The second one helped a ton. Thanks man.

Comment: You're welcome! As an added tip, I'd suggest that you call `circle.Dispose()` when you are done using it, or else you will get memory leaks.  Glad I could help.

Comment: Forcing an irregular UI update by `Update` or `Refresh` is generally a bad practice. It is usually the sign that UI is already suffocating due to `Thread.Sleep` or other blocking operation, which makes the UI totally unresponsive. It blocks not just all mouse and other events but also the regular `WM_PAINT` event to do its job. You should use a timer instead, and just set the new image in its `Tick` event. Or, even better, just call `picBox.Invalidate()` in `Tick`, and draw the ball yourself in `Paint` by `Graphics.FillEllipse`. It will be much faster than the terribly slow `SetPixel`.